# why does tableview taking so much time to update?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

i currently have a UITableView that shows me a list of people with the particular events which has been derived from the facebook.
I currently have no issues fetching and inserting in core data,but the amount of time it takes to update the tableview is probably around 12 secs

User first selects an event

Then enters the edit screen

changes the event type to anniversary(balloons)

I navigate the same way back home,but here lies the problem,
my tableview updates to the anniversary type event after probably 12 seconds.why is there so much delay in updating the tableview

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";

//testing


EventCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
PersonEvent *currentEvent = [self.eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell configureForEvent:currentEvent];
//  NSLog(@"Event date is %@",[currentEvent.eventDate description]);
// NSLog(@"Time interval %f",[currentEvent timeDifference]);
//[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;

}
```

**configureForEvent**

```
-(void)configureForEvent:(PersonEvent*)theEvent
 {

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //performing async operation her

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        personLabel.text = theEvent.name;
        dateLabel.text = [theEvent getFriendlyDate];
        //  NSInteger theAge = [theEvent getAge];
        if (theEvent.hasAge) {
            //  NSLog(@"Have to load the age as well for %@",theEvent.name);
            ageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d yrs",[theEvent getAge] ];
        }
        else{
            ageLabel.text = @"";
        }

        //ageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d yrs",[theEvent getAge] ];
        reminderImage.image = [theEvent.theReminders count] == 0?[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminder.png"]:nil;
        // Have to configure event type image based on the event type..
        //NSLog(@"Event image %@",[eventTypeImagesArray objectAtIndex:theEvent.eventType]);
        eventTypeImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[eventTypeImagesArray objectAtIndex:theEvent.eventType]];;

        // Update UI
        // Example:
        // self.myLabel.text = result;
    });
});



}
```

loadAllEventz-method which is called on initWithNibName

```
-(void)loadAllEventz
{
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PersonEvent" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"eventDate" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSError *error;
    allEventsArray = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",allEventsArray); 
//  [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequestAsynchronously:fetchRequest delegate:self];


 }
```

PersonEvent Class is a NSManagedObject subclass

Comment: Any particular reason for using GCD in configureForEvent: method?

Comment: Also it will be helpful if you can post the code where you populate/fetch the data source

Comment: i purposely did it so that it speeds up..well that isnt helping

Comment: The async part of the GCD block is blank, you are doing everything on the main queue. So effectively it is not helping. I would suggest you to remove that and keep the function simple. As for the performance part, it depends how you are populating the data source.

Comment: What is the core data operation you perform when your user updates the event type? After the update is done how do you repopulate the table view data source?

Comment: i have added the fetch request,and for the question you asked above,i filter out my data depending on the events first(e.g on top left you can see filter,it filters out birthday,anniversary,wedding etc) and then i reload the table

Comment: It is difficult to point out issues if code is not available, however I can advise you to move all core data fetch/save/update operations on background thread (make use of NSOperation, NSOperationQueue or GCD). Read following tutorial for performing core data operations on background threads..[link](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/)

Comment: Please put your image operation code in an asynchronous method

Comment: @vin Quick check: You can move the executeFetchRequest: call in an async GCD block. Once the data set fetch is complete, just call reloadData on your table from main queue.

Comment: @Amar i added gcd block as you said, it is updating quickly on the simulator but not on the device

Comment: Can you post the snippet how you are calling in GCD?

Comment: @Amar http://pastebin.com/AZ5TZTLv

Comment: @vin: Code looks fine to me!
Remember, managed object context is thread specific. For taking operations completely off the main thread you need to create background thread, create new context instance for this thread and then do the necessary operations, merge them with the main thread context. Pass the result back to the main thread to update the UI. This will be a robust solution to your performance problem. Refer to tutorial link in my previous comments.

Comment: @vin: For fetching results you can try this code.. Let me know if it improves performance on device....http://pastebin.com/WwDjACNL

Comment: @Amar i used your code but it doesnt show me anything now,only disclosure indicators

Comment: Check if allEventsArray is having data returned from executeFetchRequest: method call.

Comment: @Amar well it returns null,i dont understand how come?

Comment: @vin The fetchRequest also needs to be created in the GCD block. Assign the new managedObjectContext instance in the fetchRequest and then try.

Comment: @Amar still it is null..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29913/discussion-between-amar-and-vin)

Answer (score 0):

the tableview performance depend on the datasource methods.

in your code you implemented GCD but the running is done in the mainthread itself!!

Problem for beign slow is the image loading.Make use of GCD in insearting image or use classes like Asynchimageview /AFnetworking extention,SDWebimageView etc

Comment: when i edit an event and change the name,it also takes 12 secs to update,i suppose it has nothing got to do with image loading

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am looking at this all wrong, but when an event is updated, are you sending the update to the web-service and then retrieving from the web-service when you go back to the `TableView`?  If so, that seems highly inefficient.  Since you know the data that has changed, why not use a `delegate` method (or `unwind segue`) to send the update back to the `TableView` and then just send the update to the web-service in the background?  Unless you are needing information that you don't already have, there shouldn't be a reason to poll the web-service again.  From looking at your flow, it seems that you are re-polling the web-service to get an update that you already know about.

Also, on the images.  It sure looks like a small static group of images you are using for the reminders.  Why not download them once (upon initial load of app) and then use the ones stored locally so you are not fetching them each time.

Comment: no i am not sending any update to the webservice,basically i am taking webservice to retrieve the data and insert it in core data,and then retreive it accordingly,but still it is slowing down,i dont understand why

Answer (score 0):

UITableView works fast. The problem isn't in tableView. You'd better measure elapsed time on yours "performing async operation".